# Payload with get method in Google APP script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to send payload using get method in GAS and it keeps failing. I was able to do that in Google cloud function using nodejs but I can't do this in Google app script. ANY SUGGESTIONS on how to send a params in the body for get method in Google app script?

I have tried `urlfetchapp` with method get

Comment: I have deleted my original answer since now the question is edited and concerns only sending a payload with a GET request.  It looks like `UrlFetchApp` does not allow it even if `method: "GET"` is set explicitly: once there is a payload, `UrlFetchApp` sends a POST request instead of GET.  Documentation [says](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app): "Certain HTTP methods (for example, GET) do not accept a payload."  I am not aware of a workaround short of proxying it through some other service that would accept POST and "convert" it into GET.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.